# Nesting of classes in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have two class elements both with almost the same properties.
I want to nest both of them.

```
<a class="pa"  href="test.html">Home</a>
<a class="pb"  href="pics.html">Pics</a>
```

Their CSS is:

```
.pa:hover {
border: 2px solid #82D900;
background-color: #82D900;
background-color: #82D900;
color: white;
}


.pb:hover {
 border: 2px solid #82D900;
background-color: #82D900;
color: white;
}
```

help plz!

Comment: Those do have the same properties. In `.pa:hover` you just repeated `background-color`.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to imply by "nest"? (I'm assuming the repeated `background-color` is a typo)

Comment: Yeah sorry that repeated background-color is a typo.
By nesting I meant that I want to write it like this:
<h1>Hello!</h1>
<p>How are you</p>

h1 {
p {
color: red;
}
}

Comment: So then they are exactly the same. What are you trying to nest? Why not just make both of them class `pa`?

Comment: or just point both to the same css:
`.pa:hover, .pb:hover { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two blocks of css with the same properties, you can join them like so:

```
.pa:hover, .pb:hover {
    border: 2px solid #82D900;
    background-color: #82D900;
    color: white;
}
```

If they are mostly the same you can put the properties the same in a block like above, then have the differences in their own blocks like:

```
.pa:hover, .pb:hover {
    --- same properties ---
}

.pa:hover {
    --- properties unique to .pa:hover ---
}

.pb:hover {
    --- properties unique to .pb:hover ---
}
```